# Align vector and raster layers with D3

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, d3

I have a geocoded raster image that I want to use as the background to a vector map with D3.js. The screenshot shows the layers in QGIS (grey is raster). Here's the markup for the map:

`<div class="container"> <-- has raster image as background-image -->
    <svg></svg>
</div>`

[image: image in Qgis]
Also, see [this map from the New York Times](http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2014/12/31/world/middleeast/isis-airstrikes-map.html) for an example of what I'm aiming for. My question is: How do I make the vector layers and the background image align in the browser?

I think this is the relevant code sections from the NYT, but I'm not sure how to apply it to my own project:

```
var background = $('.the-background');
var basemapAspectRatio = 0.6244;
var mapCenter = [42.45,32.42];
var mapScale = 2.288;
var mapRatio = 7000 / 4371;
var mapHeight = background.height();
var trueWidth = mapHeight * mapRatio;
var mapWidth = background.width();

projection = d3.geo.mercator()
  .center(mapCenter)
  .scale(trueWidth * mapScale)
  .translate([mapWidth / 2, mapHeight / 2]);
```

Comment: There is a good  [example](http://bl.ocks.org/milkbread/5885443) of doing this with Leaflet and D3.js. The general idea is to attach the svg to the map div `var svgContainer= d3.select(map.getPanes().overlayPane).append("svg");` and then rescale the svg bounds based on the map bounds, reprojected to screen coordinates using the supplied d3 projection. The path is then reprojected in same way and attached to svg container.

Comment: @JohnBarça That is a different issue, with a slippy. The example uses a static basemap.

Comment: @durrrutti Did you ever figure this out?